# Check if character `'a'` is separated from `'b'` by three places

Tags: java

folks. I'm doing every problem on `codebyte.com` (I suggest website to everyone who wants to practice coding skills :)) and got stuck at this problem: return `true` if the characters `a` and `b` are separated by exactly ``3 places anywhere in the string at least once; else return `false`.
Examples:

```
Input = "after badly" Output = "false"
Input = "Laura sobs" Output = "true"
```

My code is giving me `false` every time I write any `string` when in some cases it should return `true`. Could smb please take a look?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter any String: ");
            String myString = kbd.nextLine();
            char[] myArray = myString.toCharArray();
            boolean result = false;

            for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
            {
                if(myArray[i] == 'a' && myArray[i+4] == 'b')
                    result = true;
                else 
                    result = false;
            }
            System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Why i+4? I thought you wanted 3 places, not 4.

Comment: Calculate the difference of `String#indexOf` between the two values?

Comment: I am very surprised you don't get an arrayindexoutofboundsexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you find it is true, you are going to want to print True and exit from the for loop. As of now you continue going through the string even if you find a true value!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter any String: ");
        String myString = kbd.nextLine();
        char[] myArray = myString.toCharArray();
        boolean result = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(myArray[i] == 'a' && myArray[i+4] == 'b'){
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);

}
```

Also it is unclear if you are looking for strings like "adddb" or "addb"
because the former is i+4 and the latter is i+3

Comment: AAAAAAAHHH! :) Thank you! Totally forgot to include `break`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple break statement will help you here. In your for loop, just place in under the if condition right after you set the result to true. If we find the case where there is 3 spaces between 'a' and 'b' we want to get out of the loop and tell the user! The break statement will automatically terminate the loop for you.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
   if(myArray[i] == 'a' && myArray[i+4] == 'b'){
      result = true;
      break;
   }
   else 
     result = false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`i+4` is four spaces, if you want three use `i+3`. Also, check the length - 3. Also, `break;` if you set `result` to `true` (or the next iteration will reset it). Like

```
boolean result = false;
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length - 3; i++) {
    if (myArray[i] == 'a' && myArray[i+3] == 'b') {
        result = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you play with array index you might end with arrayIndexOutOfBoundException. Rather use regular expressions

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter any String: ");
    String myString = kbd.nextLine();
    boolean result = false;

    if(myString.matches("^(.)*(a)(.){3}(b)(.)*$")){
        result = true;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```